# Use properties on storybook component template

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

Using a class component in a story enables you to pass through properties as arguments:

```
const Template: Story<MyComponent> = (args) => ({
  props: args,
  component: MyComponent,
})

export const Default = Template.bind({});

export const Small = Template.bind({});
Small.args = {
  size: 'xs'
}
```

Magically the arguments are mapped over as props to the component. However, when using a template it does not work:

```
const Template: Story<FlexDialogModalComponent> = (args) => ({
  props: args,
  template: `
    <app-my-component>test</app-my-component>
  `,
})
```

Now it seems obvious since it does not know where to add them. So I figured the following should be possible:

```
const Template: Story<FlexDialogModalComponent> = (args: { dialogModalSize }) => ({
  props: args,
  template: `
    <app-my-component [size]="size">test</app-my-component>
  `,
})
```

But that does not work. It gives no error but it just does nothing. Someone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few examples that I think that could help you with your problem.

```js
// my-component.ts
import {
  Component,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() size: string;
}
```

```html
<!--my-component.html-->
{{size}}
```

```js
// my-component.stories.ts
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';
import { MyComponent } from './my-component';

export default {
  title: 'MyComponent',
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
      ], declarations: [
        MyComponent
      ]
    })
  ]
};

export const Component = () => ({
  component: MyComponent,
  props: {
    size: 'xs'
  }
})

// "@storybook/addon-controls" is needed (.storybook/main.js) so that you can play with the 'size' property in Storybook in the 'Controls' tab
export const Template = (args) => ({
  template: `<app-my-component [size]="size"></app-my-component>`,
  props: args
})
Template.args = {
  size: 'xs'
}

// "@storybook/addon-controls" is needed (.storybook/main.js) so that you can play with the 'size' property in Storybook in the 'Controls' tab
export const ComponentWithControls = (args) => ({
  component: MyComponent,
  props: args
})
ComponentWithControls.args = {
  size: 'm'
}
```